# Upload XML (with repetitive element) using REST POST Service

Tags: rest, post

I want to upload xml using rest post service. I have deployed post service working fine with normal xml. When I am trying to upload XML with list of same element:

`Customer` and `Order` are list type element and value set to null at server side. I have taken list type `List<CustomerType> customerDetail` for customer and `orderlist`.

If I make it simple `CustomerType customerDetail` and upload one customer xml then it is uploaded successfully.

But when I take `List/Array/Observablecollection` and upload multiple customers in single xml the the customer details are set to null.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand exactly what your problem is from the way you wrote this, but my guess is that you are trying to post a collection of customers and have multiple root nodes in your doc, like this:

```
<customer>
   <someNode />
</customer>
<customer>
    <someOtherNode />
</customer>
```

which is invalid XML.

You have two possible solutions, if that is your problem.  First, do a foreach loop and post each customer individually.  Simple, quick, but resource intensive on your REST server side.  Second, add a customer batch node for collections to serve as your root node, with multiple customer nodes inside of that, and add the capability to deal with this on the REST server side (another foreach, but with only one http call to the server, thus fewer resources used).  This is more complicated, but in the end is a better way to do it.  Your new XML doc would probably look something like this:

```
<customerCollection>
<customer>
   <someNode />
</customer>
<customer>
    <someOtherNode />
</customer>
</customerCollection>
```

Comment: I am using <CustomerList>
  <CustomerCount>3</CustomerCount>
  <Customer>
  <FirstName>Andrew</FirstName>
   <LastName>Strauss</LastName>
   <OrderList>
  <Order>
   <Id>12356</Id>
   <Date>02-02-12</Date>
  </Order>
  <Order>
   <Id>55555</Id>
   <Date>02-05-12</Date>
  </Order>
   </OrderList>
  </Customer>  
  <Customer>
 <FirstName>Fname</FirstName>
 <LastName>Lname</LastName>
   <OrderList>
  <Order>
   <Id>44444</Id>
   <Date>05-02-12</Date>
  </Order>
   </OrderList>
  </Customer>  
</CustomerList>